# Java-Does mappedbytebuffer occupy direct memory?

Tags: java, mappedbytebuffer, off-heap

I am curious whether the mappedbytebuffer occupies direct memory in Java? As mentiond in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)

> A direct byte buffer may also be created by mapping a region of a file directly into memory

When I map a file into memory, the direct memory should be used. But I started a program with JVM param "-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=200MB" then I tried to map a file of 1GB into memory, it worked. What's more, I allocated a directByteBuffer with 200MB first and then tried to map the file of 1GB into memory, and it still worked! So, which part of the memory does mappedbytebuffer occupy?

Comment: What do you think the word "may" in that quote means? Your question is "Does it"? The word "may" is the answer: Perhaps! Maybe! Could be! Unknown! Depends! --- Any other words that would help you understand it?

Comment: What is the point in using a MMF bigger than your heap? that defeats the purpose of wiring the file into memory.

Answer (score 1):

i think,when you map a bigger file into small  memory, the instance of `mappedbytebuffer`  may  mapping a region of a file which you have just used
 into memory ,then the other region which have been map in memory  will exchange into  SWAP(the virtual  memory on hard disk ) by MMU